Why am I gettting error Icon in cachednetworkImage
I am getting error icon in my cached network image. The code snippet is as below:
class FacCachedNetworkImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FacCachedNetworkImage(
      {required this.imageUrl, super.key, this.isFullScreenEnable = false});

  final String imageUrl;
  final bool? isFullScreenEnable;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (isFullScreenEnable == true) showLightBox(context, imageUrl);
      },

      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        placeholder: (context, url) =>
            const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }
}

I verified the function receives a valid image url as argument. But it gives an error icon to display. Why does that happen?

It's hard to tell without a sample link, but it could be that the format of the loaded image is unsupported.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain#/media/File:Everest_North_Face_toward_Base_Camp_Tibet_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg

Above link was used.

Well, the link is incorrect as it is not just the image. Use this instead.
